# Why am I getting this error back using TSQL Pivot?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have this simple select, that works:

```
select CASE_NUM, 
  OpDate, 
  LOCATION, 
  FLOWSHEET_ROW , 
  MEAS_VALUE , 
  Surgeon, 
  SD, 
  ED , 
  Ranking 
from #output o
```

but when I try pivoting the table it does not

```
select
  CASE_NUM, 
  OpDate, 
  LOCATION, 
  FLOWSHEET_ROW , 
  MEAS_VALUE , 
  Surgeon, 
  SD, 
  ED , 
  Ranking
from #output o
pivot 
( 
  max(MEAS_VALUE) 
  for FLOWSHEET_ROW in ([R PNEUMATIC COMPRESSORS INITIATED],[R AN ANTIBIOTIC ADMINISTERED])
) as Checklist
```

**Error Message:**

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 Invalid column name 'MEASURE_VAL'. Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Invalid column name 'FLOWSHEET_ROW'.

Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Why am I getting this error?`, what error **are** you getting?. Also, do you know how `PIVOT` works?

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Invalid column name 'MEASURE_VAL'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid column name 'FLOWSHEET_ROW'.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Can you create a script that fully reproduces the problem?   The error mentions `Measure_Val` which doesn't appear anywhere in the query you posted.   I suspect you are not giving us the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message you are getting the problem is that you are using the `MEASURE_VAL`. and `FLOWSHEET_ROW` columns inside of your PIVOT call so they are no longer available for your final select list.  You should use a subquery or specifically name the columns you want to select in the final list. An example would be:

```
select 
  CASE_NUM, 
  OpDate, 
  LOCATION,
  Surgeon, 
  SD, 
  ED , 
  Ranking,
  [R PNEUMATIC COMPRESSORS INITIATED],[R AN ANTIBIOTIC ADMINISTERED]
from
(
  select
    CASE_NUM, 
    OpDate, 
    LOCATION, 
    FLOWSHEET_ROW , 
    MEAS_VALUE , 
    Surgeon, 
    SD, 
    ED , 
    Ranking
  from #output
) o
pivot 
( 
  max(MEAS_VALUE) 
  for FLOWSHEET_ROW in ([R PNEUMATIC COMPRESSORS INITIATED],[R AN ANTIBIOTIC ADMINISTERED])
) as Checklist;
```

As you can see the `MEAS_VALUE` and the `FLOWSHEET_ROW` have been replaced in the final select list with your new columns `R PNEUMATIC COMPRESSORS INITIATED`, `R AN ANTIBIOTIC ADMINISTERED`.

Answer (score 0):

Since pivot FLOWSHEET_ROW will be pivoted to different columns as below:

```
select   CASE_NUM, 
  OpDate, 
  LOCATION, [R PNEUMATIC COMPRESSORS INITIATED],[R AN ANTIBIOTIC ADMINISTERED]
from
( select
CASE_NUM, 
OpDate, 
LOCATION, 
FLOWSHEET_ROW , 
MEAS_VALUE , 
Surgeon, 
SD, 
ED , 
Ranking
  from #output o
) a
  pivot 
( 
  max(MEAS_VALUE) 
  for FLOWSHEET_ROW in ([R PNEUMATIC COMPRESSORS INITIATED],[R AN ANTIBIOTIC ADMINISTERED])
) as Checklist
```